# Trying to implement SHA-1

Tags: matlab, encryption, hash, cryptography, sha

I am trying to implement SHA-1 code, but i am getting some weird output when i am trying to compute the 80 words of 32 bit length, here is the pseudocode.

```
 message='Hello';
 message=dec2bin(message,8);
  message=reshape(message,1,40);  
message(end:end+1)=0;
a=repmat('0', 1, 409);
message=strcat(message,a);
lengthh=length(dec2bin(40,8));
a=repmat('0', 1, 64-lengthh);
b=dec2bin(40,8);
 message=strcat(message,a,b);
k=1;
s='';
M=repmat(s,16,32);
W= repmat(s,80,32);
for i=1:32:512
M(k,:)=message(i:i+31);
 k=k+1;
end
Hash(1,:)  =dec2bin(hex2dec('67452301'),32);
Hash(2,:) = dec2bin(hex2dec('efcdab89'),32);
Hash(3,:) = dec2bin(hex2dec('98badcfe'),32);
Hash(4,:) = dec2bin(hex2dec('10325476'),32);
Hash(5,:) =dec2bin(hex2dec('c3d2e1f0'),32);

W(1:16,:)=M(1:16,:);
for i=17:80
 W(i,:)=  bitxor(uint32(W(i-3,:)),uint32(W(i-8,:)),'uint32');
 end
```

The output is

val =

```
   00000111110111100000101110111100
   00101000000000000000000000000000
   00000000000000000000000000000000
   00000000000000000000000000000000
   00000000000000000000000000000000
    00000000000000000000000000000000
   00000000000000000000000000000000
  00000000000000000000000000000000
  00000000000000000000000000000000
    00000000000000000000000000000000
  00000000000000000000000000000000
   00000000000000000000000000000000
  00000000000000000000000000000000
  00000000000000000000000000000000
    00000000000000000000000000000000
   00000000000000000000000000101000



         00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000101000


00000000000000000000000000101000



00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000101000

00000000000000000000000000101000


00000000000000000000000000101000

00000000000000000000000000101000





00000000000000000000000000101000

00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000101000

00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000101000


00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000101000


00000000000000000000000000101000

00000000000000000000000000101000

00000000000000000000000000101000


00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000101000


00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000101000

00000000000000000000000000101000

00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000101000




00000000000000000000000000101000
```

The problem starts with the 17th row, some weird symbols start appearing, can somebody help.

Comment: I see a lot of ascii `48`, `49`, `0`, and `1` showing up in `W`. What were you expecting? I will readily admit that I'm not very familiar with SHA-1 encoding, but I am familiar with MATLAB and bit operations. It would be helpful if you commented your code or at least gave some description of what you're doing. For example, line 2 gives an error (at least in Octave), and I'm pretty sure line 3 doesn't do what you think it does (you should check the output carefully.) I don't understand why you're changing the last char `1` in `message` to a numeric `0` and appending another numeric `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to avoid implementing the hashing algorithm on your own; this can be a pain, especially in Matlab. Use the built-in Java hashing framework instead, which is lightning-fast and bullet-proof:

```
% Your message to be hashed...
message = 'Hello';

% Convert the message into a byte array...
message_bytes = getByteStreamFromArray(double(message));

% Create an instance of a Java MessageDigest with the desired algorithm:
md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA-1');
md.update(message_bytes);

% Properly format the computed hash as an hexadecimal string:
hash = reshape(dec2hex(typecast(md.digest(),'uint8'))',1,[]);
```

The output will be `F7FF9E8B7BB2E09B70935A5D785E0CC5D9D0ABF0`. You can verify the correctedness of the results with [this online application](http://www.convertstring.com/Hash/SHA1), for example.

Comment: In my case, getByteStreamFromArray cause the result to be wrong. Simply feeding the data to the "update" method as an array of unit8 does it. Your code, when used as is, doesn't produce the expected hash.